# Laravel version upgrade with routes.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-7, laravel-upgrade

Laravel had a **routes.php** file in older version. Which got changed into **routes/web.php** I am trying to upgrade the laravel from older to latest version. But my routes.php still exists and routes folder is not still created.

Is this fine, because the code works fine till now.

Comment: There's two (or three) repositories to consider. [Framework](https://github.com/laravel/framework) which is what is actually upgraded and [Laravel](https://github.com/laravel/laravel) which is the boilerplate code which contains your own code which you as the programmer are responsible to rewrite and modify to make compatible with any newer version if required.  The [upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade) for each version should tell you what changes are necessary to your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your `RouteServiceProvider.php`. That's where you find the definition of the routes files.

If you perform a true upgrade I would suggest to also update file paths. Just makes it easier to understand code of you have multiple laravel projects or when switching developers.